# How to add proporties to {this.props.children} after async call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, relay

I have the following React components:

A QueryRenderer component to fire the async call and retrieve results (a `Spinner` is shown while loading, and an `MessageBar` in case of error)

```
class AppQueryRenderer extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        onContent: PropTypes.func,
        query: PropTypes.func,
        variables: PropTypes.object
    };

    getContent = props => {
        if (this.props.onContent) return this.props.onContent(props);
        else throw new Error("ERROR(AppQueryRenderer): No content to handle.");
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <QueryRenderer
                environment={environment}
                query={this.props.query}
                variables={this.props.variables}
                render={({ error, props }) => {
                    if (error) {
                        return (
                            <MessageBar alarm>{error.message}</MessageBar>
                        );
                    } else if (props) {
                        return this.getContent(props);
                    }

                    return <Spinner />;
                }}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Here is a common page loader that will get page data from server and render the result:

```
const PageLoaderQuery = graphql`
    query PageLoaderQuery($pageName: String!) {
        viewer {
            load(pageName: $pageName) {
                pageConfig {
                    item
                    value
                }
                pageData
            }
        }
    }
`;

class PageLoader extends Component {
    handleContent = props => {
        let Component = this.props.children;

        // ERROR HERE - data PROPERTY IS NOT BEING
        // PASSED DOWN TO CHILD COMPONENT
        return <Component data={props.viewer.pageData}/>;
    };

    render = () => {
        return (
            <AppQueryRenderer
                onContent={this.handleContent}
                query={PageLoaderQuery}
                variables={{
                    pageName: this.props.pageName
                }}
            />
        );
    };
}
```

And a simple page component, that will behave depending on page code and data.

```
class MyPage extends Component {

    render = () => {
        // NOT GETTING THE PAGE DATA FROM data PROPERTY

        let comp = <h1>**ERROR**</h1>;
        if (this.props.data)
            comp = (
                <span>
                    <h1>MY DATA:</h1>
                    <h1>{this.props.data}</h1>
                </span>
            );

        return <PageLoader pageName={"MyPage"}>{comp}</PageLoader>;
    };
}
```

The loadeded `props` is not being passed down to `this.props.children` at `PageLoader`. I'getting the following error:

```
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

I've tried also the `React.cloneComponent` to clone children:

```
   handleContent = props => {
        const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(
            this.props.children,
            child => React.cloneElement(child, { data: props.viewer.pageData })
        );

        return childrenWithProps;
    };
```

Got the same problem. The `data` props is not shown on children.

Any ideas of how to solve that?

Comment: There's a syntax error in line `return <Component data={props.viewer.pageData/>;`. A missing ending curly brace. Is that fixed in your source code?

Comment: Yes. Fixed here.

Comment: I believe it's already late but you need to create a fragment inside each child component and then add that fragment into your top parent QueryRenderer. once data is fetched you need to pass it down to your child components